# Running Python scripts with Xampp

Tags: python, apache, xampp

I'm using python 2.7.13
At first the browser was showing the raw code.

what I did:

#### Edited httpd.conf

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp .py
```

At the top of all my scripts I added this:

```
#!j:/Installeds/Python/python   
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
```

Now it's giving me `Internal Server Error (500)` and I have no idea what else to try... First time with python.

Obs: I think this may help> `Apache>Error.log`

> [cgi:error] [pid 6364:tid 1620] (9)Bad file descriptor: [client ::1:51083] AH01222: don't know how to spawn child process: C:/Files and Installs/Xampp/htdocs/Test/main.py
> AH02102: C:/Files and Installs/Xampp/htdocs/Test/main.py is not executable; ensure interpreted scripts have "#!" or "'!" first line

Answer (score 56):

## Run Python in XAMPP for Windows

### Step 1: Download and Install Python

Download and install the latest version of Python from https://www.python.org/downloads.

### Step 2: Configure XAMPP for Python

Open the Apache `httpd.conf` configuration file located at `.../xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf` using a text editor of your choice.

The XAMPP GUI can also quickly access the `httpd.conf` file:

[image]

Copy and paste the following code at the end of the file:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .py
ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict
```

#### Step 2.5: Add Python extension to default page locations (Optional)

Inside the `httpd.conf` file search for `<IfModule dir_module>` to add `index.py` among others to the list of default page locations.

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm index.py \
    default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html default.htm default.py \
    home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm home.py
</IfModule>
```

### Step 3: Restart Apache / XAMPP

If Apache was running while editing, now is the time to restart it.

### Step 4: Run Python from XAMPP

Create a folder and Python file in the XAMPP `htdocs` directory; e.g.  `.../xampp/htdocs/PythonProject/test.py`.

At the beginning of your script, you first need to specify the directory of your Python executable. The default location of Python 3.10.0 is `C:/Users/<YOUR_WINDOWS_PROFILE>/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe`, but in your case, it may be different, depending on the version and directory in which you've installed Python.

```
#! C:/Users/<YOUR_WINDOWS_PROFILE>/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe
```

After that, you can create your Python script.

```
#! C:/Users/<YOUR_WINDOWS_PROFILE>/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe

print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print("Hello, World!")
```

Save the file and open `localhost/PythonProject/test.py` in your web browser. Your Python script should be running.

Comment: YouTube version: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQZoNZuJ-wE

Comment: You must remove any tab / spaces before the `#!` for this to work.

Comment: Great answer! It doesn't seem to be needed to add `ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict` though, so you may want to edit it out.

Answer (score 6):

Im running ubuntu 16.04 so my answer might be a little different. I am using a google chrome browser with a python 3 file called test.py in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PythonProject:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# first line is the interpreter to be executed
# No blank lines are accepted...

#test.py

print('Content-type: text/html\r\n\r')
print("<p>hello world!</p>")
print("I can view this in my browser yay!!")
```

I edited my httpd.conf file in /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf and I did **not** add

```
AddHandler cgi-script .py
ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict
```

to the end of the file, instead I added **.py** to the end of the existing line

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
```

finally i made the file executable by `chmod +x /opt/lampp/htdocs/PythonProject/test.py` and then I just ran it through my browser:

```
http://localhost/PythonProject/test.py
```

OUTPUT:

```
hello world!

I can view this in my browser yay!!
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Download python from here (https://www.python.org/downloads/) and install it
2. Open XAMPP control panel, click on config and go to httpd.conf file >> search for addhandler and add “.py” [without quotation ] just like in the screenshot (if it’s not added)
   [httpd.conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwVQp.png)
3. Restart the apache server

**To run a python script:**
Open any text editor and put this code

```
#!C:/Users/"Username"/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python.exe
print("content-type: text/html\n\n" )
print("<br><B>hello python</B>")
```

In the first line, you have to type the location of the python.exe file after putting a shebang (#!)
“username” — username of your PC
This will differ from one user to another. You can find the python location from environment variables (see the screenshot below)

[py environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brkrN.png)

- Then put the script in xampp>> htdocs folder
- Open your browser and type localhost/”filename”.py (http://localhost/filename.py)
  [ “filename”= script name]
  You’ll see this output

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLoXx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Bad File descriptor means that a file is corrupt and it says it can not run the script so you probably have python incorrectly set up.