# Python script displaying as it is on local XAMPP server

Tags: python, apache, xampp, cgi

I am running python script on my local server(Apache Server via XAMPP) using Python. Initially, the script was displaying as it was on the text editor. The code I was using was-

```
#!C:\Users\Gaurav Rai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe

def htmlTop():
    print("""
           Content-Type: text/html
          <!Doctype html>
          <html lang=en>
                 <head>
                        <meta charset="UTF-8">
                        <title>My First Server Page in Python</title>
                        </head>
                        <body>
            """)

def htmlTail():
    print("""
          </body>
          </html>
          """)

if  __name__== "__main__" :
    try:
        htmlTop()
        print("""<h1>Hello  World!</h1>""")
        htmlTail()
    except:
        cgi.print_exception()
```

The output coming was -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOxtU.png)

after taking help from- [Running Python scripts with Xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42704846/running-python-scripts-with-xampp)

I changed my code to-

```
def htmlTop():
    print("""Content-Type: text/html""")
    print("""
          <!Doctype html>
          <html lang=en>
                 <head>....(remaining code is same)
```

After doing this change the code was working fine and the required output "Hello World!" was obtained on the local server.

Can anyone explain what is actually happening here?