# how to solve Server Error 500 for python on Xampp

Tags: python, macos, terminal, xampp, python-3.8

I am getting this error:

**Server error!**

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message:
End of script output before headers: python.py

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

**Error 500**

192.168.64.2
Apache/2.4.41 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1d PHP/7.4.1 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3*

I have added .py to the addhandler
[AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py
    ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CiLe.png)

I also have pip and pymysql installed and am using python 3.8.

I have also have the permissions set to chmod 755
[sudo chmod 755](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY799.png)

have also tried chmod 755, +x but no luck
I have also checked the error logs but no clear problem

btw I am using Mac

Heres my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/local/env python3
print ('Content-type: text/html\r\n')
print ('\r\n')
print ()
print ('<html>')
print ('<head>')
print ('</head>')
print ('<body>')
print ('Hello Python')
print ('</body>')
print ('</html>')
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant lines from the error.log file Apache2 writes errors to?

Comment: `End of script output before headers: python.py`

Comment: Try making the first line go directly to you Python file. Also, this probably has nothing to do with your error, but you're going to want to change `Content-type: text/html\n\n` to end in `\r\n`: `Content-type: text/html\r\n`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757290/http-header-line-break-style

Comment: Thanks for sharing the log line.  Assuming `python.py` is placed in the correct directory, maybe just try restarting XAMPP (see  this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45476400/11553043)?

Comment: It doesn't work and I am using Mac

Comment: @wp-overwatch.com is the location supposed to be like this at the top: #!c:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3

Comment: Macs never start filepaths with C:/. On the terminal type in `which python3`, and use that filepath (with the `#!` in front of it).

Comment: @wp-overwatch.com it still doesn't affect anything

Comment: Take a look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html and make sure you've set everything up correctly. Beyond that, I don't know what to do.

Comment: `print("Content-Type: html \r\n")` return me a blank page. I am trying to load a simple `html` page