# Error while running python with xammp server

Tags: python, xampp

I am new in running python with xammp server. I have done all the required setup to run python in xammp server by following this link [Running Python scripts with Xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42704846/running-python-scripts-with-xampp). While trying to running my code i always get an error.

> **Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to
> inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
> performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
> log.**

My error log says this:
**[Tue Jan 19 10:29:34.529875 2021] [cgi:error] [pid 11652:tid 1860] [client ::1:50570] malformed header from script 'python.py': Bad header: Hello World**

i am attaching the code for my file too.

```
#! C:\Users\"UserName"\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
print("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")
import cgi

print("Hello Python")
```

i have tried everything i could to search for the solution but nothing is helping. Please help me finding a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Update the `\n\n` to use a carriage return (`\r\n\r\n`), and add another in.

This should make your HTTP headers valid, as they may not be terminating correctly.

Edit: You can also try multi-line print instructions such as

```py
print "Content-type: text/html"
print ""
```

This is interpreting the body as the header (never terminated) so terminating this correctly should fix it.

Comment: print("Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n") added this but same error

Comment: Have you looked into a framework like Flask @smartF